# meteor get data from anywhere

Tags: c, meteor

I want to get data with Objective C from my meteor project but it returns always this:

```
...
    <head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why between body tags is empty? And how do I get meteor datas from anywhere (curl, php, Objective C, iOS etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor renders the output on the browser. In essence it does this:

1. Load a html file that tells the browser how to create the page
2. Using javascript the browser will create the page
3. Fetch collections from server and fill the templates up with this

If you want to fetch data from the collections use an Objective C ddp client : https://github.com/alansikora/objective-c_ddp-client.

You might need to modify the code a bit these repos are slightly outdated, the details of the pre1 ddp protocol here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md